# How to write this linq query using Lambda expression

Tags: linq, lambda

How to write this linq query using Lambda expression

```
public List<Employee> GetList()
 {
     return (from c in DALContext.MST
             select new Employee(ID=c.CD, Name=c.NAME)).ToList();
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
public List<Employee> GetList()
{
    return DALContext.MST.Select(c => new Employee { ID = c.CD, Name = c.NAME }).ToList();
}
```

Comment: `new Employee(ID = c.CD, Name = c.NAME)` should be `new Employee{ID = c.CD, Name = c.NAME}`

Comment: @Metro of course you're right - I was focussing on the extension method bit and totally missed the syntax error.  Thanks :)

Comment: if you were using named parameters, it would be: `new Employee(ID: c.CD, Name: c.NAME)`